# Run a daemon within a namespace on a remote host. (Robot Framework)

Tags: robotframework

I'm writing a keyword in Robot Framework, that should connect to some remote host and start a daemon/server (e. g. SSH daemon) within a network namespace, presented on this remote host. I am using the SSHLibrary to build the connection to the remote host, and execute a command that should start the given daemon. The example of the keyword is below.

```
Start daemon
     ${cmd}=     Set Variable    ip netns exec NAMESPACE CMD_TO_START_DAEMON
     Open connection  REMOTE_HOST
     Login  USERNAME  PASSWORD
     ${output}=  Execute Command     ${cmd}  return_rc=True  sudo=True  sudo_password=SUDO_PSWD
     Should Be Equal As Integers  ${output}[1]  0
```

The problem is, that with this implementation nothing will be started. The keyword also reports no errors. The output looks like this:

```
${output} = [sudo] password for USERNAME:
```

The sudo password is correct. If I execute the same command in the terminal on the remote host directly, it works perfectly. If I try to start the daemon, not in the namespace, but on the remote host itself using the "Execute Command"-keyword, it works also. The keyword also does a great job, if I want just execute a command within a namespace, but then I try to start a daemon, I always run into this problem.
The same problem, if I use the "Start Command"-keyword instead of "Execute Command".

The remote host is an Ubuntu Server(18.04.3)

Maybe someone has an explanation for this behavior? Or maybe any suggestion on how I can do the same in some other way?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If it's possible to login as root add your public key and login with keyword `Login With Public Key`.
2. If you can't connect to server as root user you try interactive shell instead

Like this

```
Write  sudo su
Write  valid_sudo_password
Write  ${cmd}
```

Comment: I have picked the second option with an interactive shell, and it works for me! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good to hear, don't forget to accept the answer as solution.